# Did anybody expect Russie to invade?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nato

Russia have always stated that Ukraine into NATO was a "red line" issue. It doesn't seem like that statement was respected, and now here we are, with Russia invading Ukraine.

My question is, was this an issue of NATO and Ukraine calling the bluff of Russia, and then being surprised at the invasion, or was this an issue of NATO and Ukraine down-right expecting the invasion?

I think the answer to this question is highly relevant, since if it is the former, i.e. Russian invasion was NOT expected but merely considered a bluff, then it is highly likely that Ukraine, now realizing the gravity of Russia's threats, will agree to peace terms that may involve distansting themselves from NATO.

However, if it is the latter that is the case, i.e. Ukraine expected Russian aggression all along but still maintained their desire to join NATO, then I find it highly unlikely that there is a peaceful resolution to this war.

So... which one is it?

Comment: You're really just asking for us to read people's minds. The US government *repeatedly* said that Russia was planning to invade, that they had decided to invade, and that they were going to invade imminently. So, the answer to your stated question is obvious, while what I think you're really asking is impossible to answer

Comment: The question is when. 12 hours before it happened, the expectation of an invasion was widespread. a year ago far fewer expected it, before 2007, it would have been a great surprise.

Answer (score 2):

Expectations need not be *binary*.

I interpret this question as being less about the days up until the recent invasion (or even up until 2014), and more about generally the question: "What will happen if Ukraine makes closer ties with NATO and the EU?" if it were asked several years ago.

Because Ukraine did make some steps towards strengthening ties with Europe over Russia, we can merely conclude that the government of Ukraine thought that there was a net benefit to the country (and/or its leadership) to closer ties with Europe. That assessment would have been based on weighted assumptions about various possible scenarios. That could include calculations about whether Russia was likely to attack if the country joined or moved to join the EU or NATO. It could also include calculations about what was likely to happen if they *did not*: for example, would a Ukraine *isolated from Europe* be under risk of a Russian invasion or political takeover (something like has occurred with Belarus, for example). It would also include calculations that have little to do with Russia at all: issues of economic prosperity, for example.

Decision makers do not simply assume a singular "most likely" future; they must weigh the relative risks and benefits of different outcomes. Some outcomes, like global nuclear war, have sufficiently high costs that they may need to be weighted heavily in decision making *even when they are unlikely*. For events that are largely governed by the decision making of *others*, uncertainty has to be the norm.